# CakePHP: how to get recently created auto-incremented field

Tags: sql, cakephp

I have a user submit a field to the database, it validates, and makes the entry.  The primary key of this new row is auto-incremented.

The user then gets to another form where that newly created field is required.

Can anyone shed any light on this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Check out Model::getInsertID();

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->getLastInsertID();
```

[cakephp model docs](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/model#method-ModelgetLastInsertID)

Answer (score 1):

```
// Save the first form    
$this->Ingredient->save($newData);
// Get the id of the record just saved
$newIngredientId = $this->Ingredient->id;
// Redirect to a new form
$this->redirect(array(
  'controller' => 'dish',
  'action' => 'add',
  '?' => array('lastId' => $newIngredientId)
));
```

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data,
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1442/link

Answer (score 0):

If it's in the database, when you get to your next form just read it out again in your controller and set it to a view variable.

```
$this->set('lastid', $this->Model->read(null,$id));
```

Or if you need to search the database for the field use find

```
$this->set('lastid', $this->Model->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('username'=>'MyUserName')) , array('id')));
```

You could go around it by using `mysql_insert_id()`

Comment: Thanks!  Simple, I was thinking too much about it.

Comment: I wouldn't use mysql_insert_id().  It isn't portable and would be clunky to get to work.  That's assuming you can even get the connection resource from ConnectionManager.